# Entity Framework 6.0 With MySQL and Automatic Migration enabled Error:- RenameIndexOperation exception

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

Our application uses Entity Framework 6.0 with automatic migration enabled and our back-end in MySql. When we rename foreign key to different name, the migration failed with error `RenameIndexOperation`.

Any solution to fix this error and other expected errors that can happened on MySQL when automatic migration is enabled?

Answer (score 0):

you will have to upgrade your MySQL server to 5.7 as they have implemented the rename index in it